# Select div with class "n" after another div with another class with Jquery

Tags: jquery, html, css-selectors

I have this jquery code to add the onclick event to minimize and maximize images collapsing and expanding the div with class mainBody.

It was working before I added the div with class divSectionInfo which is now meant to expand when you click on the icon16 image and collapse divSectionInfo when close image is clicked.

I am having problems to select the next div with class mainBody skipping the div with class divSectionInfo.

Html sample

```
<span class="section" style="clear: both">
    <div class="top">
        <h2>
            <a href="javascript: void(0);">Heading </a>
            <img src='../Images/min.gif' style='float:right;' alt='minimize'/>
            <img src='../Images/max.gif' style='float:right;' alt='maximize'/>
            <img src="../Images/icon16.png" style="margin-right: 50px;" alt="expand divSectionInfo" />
        </h2>
    </div>
    <div class="divSectionInfo">
        <span>This is text</span>
        <span>This is text</span>
            <img src="../GlobalResources/Images/close.png" alt="collapse divSectionInfo"/>
        </div>
    <div>
    <div class="mainBody"></div>//This div is supposed to collapse and expand when minimize and maximize button are clicked.
    </div>
```

Jquery Code.

```
  $("img[alt='maximize']").click(function (e) {
    //alert("2");
    $(this).closest("div").next("div").slideDown("fast");
    e.stopPropagation();
    return false;
});
```

To see a working example [**HERE**](http://jsbin.com/ewanu/2), this is before adding the div with class divSectionInfo

This is afteradding the div with class divSectionInfo [**HERE**](http://jsbin.com/oriyo4)

PD: For those who dont know jsbins, you can edit  the code by clicking on the label at the top-right corner which shows up when you put the mouse in that corner and says edit edit using jsbin.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd use [`.closest()`](http://api.jquery.com/closest/) and [`.find()`](http://api.jquery.com/find/) to be the most flexible here, like this:

```
$("img[alt='maximize']").click(function (e) {
  $(this).closest(".section").find(".mainBody").slideDown("fast");
  e.stopPropagation();
});
```

[You can see your demo updated/working with this code here](http://jsbin.com/oriyo4/2).  I would give your buttons a class though, for example:

```
<img class="minimize" src='http://png.findicons.com/files/icons/653/the_spherical/32/minimize.png' style='float:right;' alt='minimize'/>
<img class="maximize" src='http://www.winnipegringette.com/images/icons/maximize.png' style='float:right;' alt='maximize'/>
```

Then change your selectors to use that, `$("img.maximize")` instead of `$("img[alt='maximize']")`.

Answer (score 1):

jQuery:

```
$(this).closest("div").siblings("div").find("div.mainBody:eq(0)")
```

Works, but you should probably go with an ID as mentioned in other answers. Basically **not** depending on a deep node hierarchy (parent `div` with sibling `div` containing `div` with class `mainBody` - the first of those, please!) but instead going to the `.section` and then find the `.mainBody` (cf. Nick Craver's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3933454/select-div-with-class-n-after-another-div-with-another-class-with-jquery/3933530#3933530)). **That way you selector is less prone to err if (when!) the markup changes.**